# Options Menu Cancel Event [Android]

Tags: android, event-handling, menu

Beginning with a basic approach -- Options Menu.

Question: What is the best way to capture a *cancel* (return) event? I.e. the user changes their mind and hits the back arrow. The issue is that I would like to *unpause* my an application thread.

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

  onPause();

  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // Handle item selection
  switch (item.getItemId()) {

  case R.id.preferences:
   Intent settingsActivity = new Intent(this, PreferencesActivity.class);
   startActivity(settingsActivity);
   return true;

  case R.id.quit:
   finish();
   return true;

  default:
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
 }
```

Is there something like @Override onCancelOptionsMenu ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the function you are looking for is [onOptionsMenuClosed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsMenuClosed%28android.view.Menu%29).

Answer (score 3):

just whith onOptionsMenuClosed() we can not distinguish if user canceled the menu with the back/menu button, or if an item was selected.

We can emulate onCancel() event by using i.e.:

onOptionsMenuClosed()
onOptionsItemSelected() 
and a boolean to keep the state:

```
private boolean bMenuCancelled = true;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
   if(item.getItemId()<= YOUR_MAX_MENU_ITEM && item.getItemId()>= YOUR_MIN_MENU_ITEM)
        bMenuCancelled = false;
   else
        bMenuCancelled = true;

   //...
}

@Override
public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu)
{
  super.onOptionsMenuClosed(menu);

  if(bMenuCancelled)
      //here the menu has been closed by clicking outside the menu
  else
      //here the menu has been closed by selecting an item

}
```